# Sticky substance exuding from morning sun facing side of Japanese Maple from China , spreading sticky, sugary over floor and furniture. Help me!

Tags: sap

I have a medium sized indoor potted Japanese Maple from China. The branches and leaves on side of the maple facing the window that receives morning sun is continually sweating a thin , but very sticky substance that falls on the blinds, the floor, the dog bed, etc. It is not only the sun facing side that produces this fluid, but the shade side is only minimally and only occasionally, sappy. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?  My apartment is a sticky mess in the area around the tree.

Comment: Hi Pam, are you able to post a photo of the plant and of an area where its coming out from

Comment: There is no such thing as an indoor Japanese Maple - all maples are outdoor trees and keeping them indoors during the summer only renders then sick, as your question highlights,  - thry need plenty of air and sunlight. In the colder months, the tree needs to go dormant but keeping it in a centrally heated home will not permit it, thus rendering it to never go dormant. If I kept you awake and hardly gave you enough resources during the daytime and kept you wide awake at night, you too might begin to show stress. Your tree needs to go outside 365 days of the year.

Comment: Have you pruned the tree at all and if so, when did you do it?  How long have you had it?

Comment: @Nikki. Thank you for this information.  My tree lived in a plant shop, in SF,CA, in a central aisle, away from all sunlight,  for over 2 yrs before I purchased it.  I was told Japanese Maples from China differ from other Japanese Maples in that they can thrive indoors .  My tree lives by an open window,receiving 5 hrs morning light.  I removed steam heating.  Apt. has no central heating.  I do however use electric lights at night.  I have not pruned the tree.  The trunk does not exude sap just the branches and leaves

Comment: @Bamboo. Thank you for replying

Comment: Better make sure that what's dripping isnt honeydew from either aphid or scale infestation - check front and back of all leaves, stems and branches, as well as the trunk for either infestation.

Comment: There is nothing at all on the branches and leaves other than the glossy sticky film. There is no white lace, normally critters. Nothing but thin glossy branches.